# How can I simplify element searching method ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I did a method checkAddedTrack() which checks if searched element added to a user playlist, but I think this method is a little bit stupid, can you make an advice to me, how can I make it in another way simpler, or smarter?

Thank you in advance!

```
function SearchListItem(props) {
  const {id, playlist, isSelected, clickHandler, index, title_short, duration, onClickAdd} = props;


  const checkAddedTrack = () => {
    let isTrackAdded = false;
    playlist.map(track => {
      if (track.id === id) {
        isTrackAdded = true;
      }
    });
    return isTrackAdded;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <li className={isSelected ? `active-song` : ``} onClick={() => {
        clickHandler(index)
      }}>
        {index + 1 + ' . '}{title_short} {formatTime(duration)}
      </li>
      <button disabled={checkAddedTrack()} onClick={onClickAdd}>
        <i className={!checkAddedTrack() ? `fa fa-plus` : `fa fa-minus`}> </i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a function at all? The value isn't going to change ever in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bit more than you need, you could use the `Array#some` method for this:

```
const checkAddedTrack = () => playlist.some(track => track.id === id)
```

The method will return a Boolean dependent on whether one or more items of that array fulfill the condition.

Considering this example for a playlist, you can use the function very easily:

```js
const playlist = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}, {id:5}, {id:6}, {id:7}, ];
let id = 5;

const checkAddedTrack = () => playlist.some(track => track.id === id)

console.log(checkAddedTrack())

id = 10;

console.log(checkAddedTrack())
```